# How to pull a "conversation" from Facebook to StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, facebook

A friend of mine posted on Facebook a question for duck-type programmers, and it started a conversation around the topic (comments after comment), that I think is more suitable for a StackOverflow question, How do I "import" that Facebook thread into a StackOverflow question?

Comment: Can you provide a link please?

Comment: That doesn't sound suitable for Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: What is a "duck-type programmer", anyhow? Do they quack? Because I only click when I program.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/roman.fq/posts/10201019689597970?comment_id=6609474&offset=0&total_comments=30&ref=notif&notif_t=feed_comment_reply

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Comment: @Yannis I understand duck typing - I was pointing out the incorrect grammar by the OP.

Comment: You don't. You absolutely don't.

Answer (score 10):

Stack Overflow works best with *specific* and answerable questions, and it's not really a platform for extended discussions. If there's a good programming question hidden somewhere in the Facebook conversation, the best thing you can do is to simply [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It shouldn't take you more than five minutes to type it in (if it's indeed a specific question and not a discussion) and you'll probably earn some rep for your effort.